# can't get value from onclick function javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I am trying to get a value from an onclick event.

Here is the element attribute that gives the function to the element:

```
listcontainer.setAttribute('onmousedown',"knowbe4campaignspecific(this)")
```

Here is the function code:

```
function knowbe4campaignspecific(ele){
    console.log(ele.value)}
```

However it will say `undefined` in the developer console.

If I just print the element by itself it will show the value inside so I must be missing something basic.

```
function knowbe4campaignspecific(ele){
    console.log(ele)}

##RESULTS##
<ul value="183085" onmousedown="knowbe4campaignspecific(this)" class="ms-List"></ul>
```

Let me know if anything else is needed and I will update this post. Thanks!

Comment: `<ul>` elements do not have a `value` property. You may be interested in [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) if you want to assign and access arbitrary data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On elements that are not inputs you want to use the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

I believe this should work

```html
<ul data-value="183085" onmousedown="knowbe4campaignspecific(this)" class="ms-List"></ul>
```

And then

```js
function knowbe4campaignspecific(ele){
    console.log(ele.dataset.value)}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, `value` isn't a valid attribute of `<ul>`. You can still use it and access it through `element.getAttribute` but using datasets is more extendable and the correct implementation - you can access those through [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
document.querySelector('.ms-List').setAttribute('onmousedown',"knowbe4campaignspecific(this)")

function knowbe4campaignspecific(ele){
    console.log(ele.getAttribute('value'))
    console.log(ele.dataset.value)
}
```

```html
<ul value="183085" data-value="This is the better way" class="ms-List"><li> something</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out as well! I think learned a little more from you since I learned you can use `element.getAttribute` to find `value`. I am using datasets now as that seems great, but I just wanted to say thanks for that extra bit of information :)